# NSLayoutManager characterIndexForPoint method failing on ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm implementing a custom `UILabel` with link clicking support. To do so, I've got the following methods: one to initialize the structures (called only once) and one to detect clicks in a determinate range of text within a string:

```
- (void) sharedInit {
    // Remember, this method is only called once
    self.layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    self.textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size];
    [self.layoutManager addTextContainer:self.textContainer];
    self.myGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];

    self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
    self.textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
    self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines;
    self.textContainer.size = self.frame.size;
}

- (void) onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) tapGesture {
    CGPoint location = [tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];
    NSInteger index = [self.layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInLabel
                                                 inTextContainer:self.textContainer
                        fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];

    NSLog(@"index of tapped character: %li", index);

    // ... and some more code to work with that index
}

- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    self.textContainer.size = self.frame.size;
}

- (void) setAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)attributedText {
    [super setAttributedText:attributedText];
    self.textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedText];
    [self.textStorage addLayoutManager:self.layoutManager];
}

- (void) setNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines {
    [super setNumberOfLines:numberOfLines];
    self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines;
}
```

The key variable here is `index` (`onTap:` mehtod). That variable returns the index of the tapped character so we can work with it. This worked flawlessly with iOS 8, but as for iOS 9 I'm seeing the following behavior:

- If the label has one line, it returns the correct index
- If the label has more than one line, *it always returns zero* no matter where did you click.

I faced a similar issue when I was developing the feature for iOS 8, and I solved it by setting the `maximumNumberOfLines` of the `NSTextContainer` to the correct value, as you can see in the initialization. The configuration parameters (size, maxNumOfLines, etc) for the TextContainer are correct when the `onTap` method is run. I've checked the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextContainer/lineFragmentRectForProposedRect:atIndex:writingDirection:remainingRect:) and apparently nothing's changed in this version, so I'm quite lost. So far, this looks like a iOS9 bug, but I don't want to discard any options. I've come with a couple of workarounds as well, but if it's possible I'd like to know what's going on with that method.

So, does anybody know what's going on? Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:**

Two things:

- I tried consulting `glyphIndex` instead of `charIndex` and so far it's returning identical results (ok with one line, zero with more than one line)
- I've noticed that the `firstUnlaidCharIndex` is equal to 0 when the result is incorrect. In cases where it works fine (iOS8 and iOS9 with just one line) it's returning the correct value, the first out-of-bounds character.

Comment: In my case, the characterIndexForPoint: method consistently returns the index of the last character of the string if I'm anywhere on the last line of a multiline label.  I see the same results regardless of whether I create the storage, container and manager dynamically or hold onto them.

Comment: @tyler, have you set the numberOfLines attribute of your NSTextContainer? I happened to run into this issue as well, and it was due to that value being equal to 1 (single line-container) even when the label had a 0. That way, clicks beyond the first line were rendered as out of bounds, so equal to the last character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Looks like the problem was the `setAttributedText:` overload. The TextStorage was re-created every time you changed the label's text, and it looks like the layout manager didn't like that at all. Reusing the textStorage and just changing the text by calling `setAttributedString:` fixed the issue.

In fact, I solved it quite a long ago :( I edited the post, but forgot to answer myself. Sorry!

Answer (score 7):

Try initing the size of the NSTextContainer with the same width of the UILabel and CGFLOAT_MAX height

```
    self.textContainer.size = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
```